# Why is /System/Library/User Template protected?

Tags: macos, filesystem

Why can't users read `/System/Library/User Template`?

Is there anything in there that is sensitive and should be protected against reading?

If `/System/Library/User Template` were not protected against reading, it'd be useful to see how a freshly created user home looks like and to restore parts of it in your own home.

Comment: A User can read `/System/Library/User Template` by using `sudo`, e.g.: `sudo ls  '/System/Library/User Template'`

Comment: @user3439894, that's what I did, but it seemed too much. Plus ordinary users cannot use `sudo`.

Comment: It's readable in Catalina.

Answer (score 1):

`/System/Library/User Template` is protected not only by its permissions, but also because of [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) as it's under `/System`

A common troubleshooting method used by system administrators is to create a new user account and see if whatever problem the user is happening is also happening there.

If, for example, a malicious Program were to infect the computer it could use the user template to perform a variety of things on all new users that are created.

It's permissions are not really meant to prevent anything sensitive from leaving, but rather prevent anything malicious from entering.

Comment: Good point, but my question is about it being protected against *reading*, not *writing*.